# android:screenOrientation in manifest portrait/lock which one is best and difference between them

Tags: android

What is the main difference between lock and portrait in screenOrientation in androidManifest.xml . Is both are same ? And which one is best for use ?

Answer (score 1):

`portrait` - Portrait orientation (the display is taller than it is wide).

`locked` - Locks the orientation to its current rotation, whatever that is. Added in API level 18.

In my opinion, if your app handles vertical and horizontal orientations, then just remove that flag. But if you want to have only vertical then use even `sensorPortrait` for better support of tablets.

For more information read here: 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen

Comment: @Nuruzzaman if I helped you, please put a checkmark to this answer